# Step Debugger not working when phpunit.xml explicitly set in configuration - PhpStorm, PHP 8, Xdebug

Tags: php, docker, phpstorm, xdebug

Hi Stack Overflow community,

Despite following all tutorials and copying a installation I have on personal computer using nginx and PHP-FPM. I am finding some very strange behaviour with a work setup which uses Apache, PHP 8.1 when trying to use the Xdebug extension.

Whenever I use PhpStorm step debugger, this will work with tests but it uses the `.env` file, if I explicitly set the `phpunit.xml` file in the PhpStorm settings to force it to use the `.env.testing` file the step debugger stops working and ignores the breakpoints. This is very strange and counter productive as I need different `.env` for all DB connections and other services that are used for tests only or not used.

## Setup

#### Add Xdebug to docker file

```
RUN yes | pecl install xdebug
RUN docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
```

#### Set `xdebug.ini` config

```ini
zend_extension=xdebug
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.mode=develop,debug
xdebug.log_level=3
xdebug.log=/tmp/log/xdebug.log
```

#### Setup PhpStorm

##### Settings > PHP > Debug

[image: Settings for debug]

##### Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Docker

Docker connected to container correctly - no errors

##### Settings > Test Frameworks

[image: If I set this config the step debugger ignores breakpoints.]

If I set this config the step debugger ignores breakpoints.

Has anyone seen this issue before?

Comment: It could be helpful to take a look at `phpunit.xml`, `.env`, `.env.testing`, and the Xdebug log when you try to debug your tests with the PHPUnit config